# How to initiate ffmpeg sendcmd at first frame of input

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, scaling

I'm trying to scale an input overlayed on an alpha background image over time using sendcmd. Everything is working as expected except the first frame of the output file isn't receiving the command marked with time 0.00, resulting in a single frame of the overlay in the top left corner before jumping to the first command-specified position at frame 2.

[Frame 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1jdZ.png)
[Frame 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYjj0.png)

I've tried specifying the initial position as part of the overlay filter in the main command:

```
[0:v][a]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-28:y=main_h-overlay_h-25[b]
```

which works until the scaling hits a certain threshold and then some sort of bug occurs:

[Resize Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psa12.jpg)

My code that works except for first frame:

```
ffmpeg -i AlphaLayer.png -i Test.mp4 -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 4444 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1360:-1:eval=init:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase[a];[0:v][a]overlay[b],[b]sendcmd=f=scale4.txt" ScaleTest.mov
```

The scale4.txt file looks like this:

```
0.00 scale w 1360, h -1;
0.00 overlay x main_w-overlay_w-28; 
0.00 overlay y main_h-overlay_h-25;
30 scale w 1560, h -1;
31 scale w 1660, h -1;
32 scale w 1760, h -1;
33 scale w 1860, h -1;
34 overlay x (main_w-overlay_w)/2;
34 overlay y (main_h-overlay_h)/2;
34 scale w 1920, h -1;
35 scale w 1360, h -1;
```

I expect the overlay to be in the specified position at frame 1 of the video, but it is in the default position until frame 2.

Output log:

```
$ ffmpeg -i AlphaLayer.png -i Test.mp4 -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 4444 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1360:-1:eval=init:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase[a];[0:v][a]overlay[b],[b]sendcmd=f=scale4.txt" Output.mov
ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'AlphaLayer.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2019-01-17T20:28:30.000000Z
  Duration: 00:02:00.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 700 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 377 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-17T20:28:31.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-17T20:28:31.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (png) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> scale (graph 0)
  sendcmd (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (prores_ks)
  Stream #1:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mov, to 'Output.mov':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: prores (prores_ks) (ap4h / 0x68347061), yuva444p10le, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 prores_ks
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-17T20:28:31.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
frame=   15 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.76 bitrate=   0.4kbits/frame=   30 fps= 29 q=-0.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:01.57 bitrate=5313.9kbits/frame=   45 fps= 29 q=-0.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:01.96 bitrate=9616.8kbits/frame=   61 fps= 29 q=-0.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:02.77 bitrate=9830.5kbits/frame=   74 fps= 27 q=-0.0 size=    4352kB time=00:00:03.17 bitrate=11216.0kbitsframe=   89 fps= 28 q=-0.0 size=    5376kB time=00:00:03.96 bitrate=11098.9kbitsframe=  103 fps= 27 q=-0.0 size=    6400kB time=00:00:04.37 bitrate=11988.4kbitsframe=  117 fps= 27 q=-0.0 size=    7168kB time=00:00:04.77 bitrate=12288.1kbitsframe=  131 fps= 27 q=-0.0 size=    8192kB time=00:00:05.56 bitrate=12052.6kbitsframe=  145 fps= 27 q=-0.0 size=    9216kB time=00:00:05.97 bitrate=12639.1kbitsframe=  157 fps= 26 q=-0.0 size=    9984kB time=00:00:06.40 bitrate=12779.6kbitsframe=  172 fps= 27 q=-0.0 size=   11264kB time=00:00:07.16 bitrate=12873.2kbitsframe=  185 fps= 26 q=-0.0 size=   12032kB time=00:00:07.57 bitrate=13014.9kbitsframe=  196 fps= 26 q=-0.0 size=   12800kB time=00:00:07.97 bitrate=13142.3kbitsframe=  206 fps= 26 q=-0.0 size=   13568kB time=00:00:08.36 bitrate=13291.1kbitsframe=  217 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=   14336kB time=00:00:08.78 bitrate=13361.7kbitsframe=  230 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=   15360kB time=00:00:09.57 bitrate=13136.4kbitsframe=  242 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=   16128kB time=00:00:09.96 bitrate=13261.6kbitsframe=  255 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=   16896kB time=00:00:10.36 bitrate=13350.0kbitsframe=  267 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=   17920kB time=00:00:10.77 bitrate=13626.3kbitsframe=  279 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=   18688kB time=00:00:11.56 bitrate=13240.2kbitsframe=  291 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=   19456kB time=00:00:11.96 bitrate=13317.5kbitsframe=  303 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=   20480kB time=00:00:12.37 bitrate=13559.2kbitsframe=  315 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=   21248kB time=00:00:12.77 bitrate=13621.4kbitsframe=  327 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=   22016kB time=00:00:13.16 bitrate=13702.0kbitsframe=  339 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=   23040kB time=00:00:13.97 bitrate=13507.4kbitsframe=  351 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=   23808kB time=00:00:14.35 bitrate=13584.4kbitsframe=  363 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=   24576kB time=00:00:14.76 bitrate=13637.6kbitsframe=  375 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=   25344kB time=00:00:15.16 bitrate=13687.9kbitsframe=  387 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   26368kB time=00:00:15.57 bitrate=13870.3kbitsframe=  399 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   27136kB time=00:00:16.36 bitrate=13585.7kbitsframe=  411 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   27904kB time=00:00:16.76 bitrate=13632.5kbitsframe=  423 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   28928kB time=00:00:17.17 bitrate=13799.2kbitsframe=  435 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   29696kB time=00:00:17.55 bitrate=13855.7kbitsframe=  447 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   30464kB time=00:00:17.96 bitrate=13893.3kbitsframe=  459 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   31488kB time=00:00:18.77 bitrate=13740.2kbitsframe=  471 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   32256kB time=00:00:19.15 bitrate=13793.2kbitsframe=  483 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   33024kB time=00:00:19.56 bitrate=13829.0kbitsframe=  495 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   34048kB time=00:00:19.96 bitrate=13968.4kbitsframe=  507 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   34816kB time=00:00:20.37 bitrate=13999.3kbitsframe=  519 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   35584kB time=00:00:21.16 bitrate=13774.5kbitsframe=  531 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   36352kB time=00:00:21.56 bitrate=13807.3kbitsframe=  543 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   37376kB time=00:00:21.97 bitrate=13934.4kbitsframe=  555 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   38144kB time=00:00:22.35 bitrate=13976.4kbitsframe=  567 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   38912kB time=00:00:22.76 bitrate=14004.0kbitsframe=  579 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   39936kB time=00:00:23.57 bitrate=13878.2kbitsframe=  590 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   40704kB time=00:00:23.97 bitrate=13906.0kbitsframe=  602 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   41472kB time=00:00:24.36 bitrate=13945.1kbitsframe=  614 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   42240kB time=00:00:24.76 bitrate=13970.9kbitsframe=  626 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   43264kB time=00:00:25.17 bitrate=14079.1kbitsframe=  637 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   44032kB time=00:00:25.60 bitrate=14090.3kbitsframe=  650 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   44800kB time=00:00:26.36 bitrate=13918.5kbitsframe=  662 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   45824kB time=00:00:26.77 bitrate=14021.1kbitsframe=  674 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   46592kB time=00:00:27.17 bitrate=14043.4kbitsframe=  685 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   47360kB time=00:00:27.56 bitrate=14076.0kbitsframe=  696 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=   48128kB time=00:00:27.96 bitrate=14097.0kbitsframe=  707 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   48896kB time=00:00:28.39 bitrate=14106.7kbitsframe=  720 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   49920kB time=00:00:29.16 bitrate=14022.9kbitsframe=  732 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   50688kB time=00:00:29.56 bitrate=14043.4kbitsframe=  744 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   51456kB time=00:00:29.97 bitrate=14063.4kbitsframe=  756 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   52480kB time=00:00:30.37 bitrate=14151.9kbitsframe=  767 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   53248kB time=00:00:30.78 bitrate=14170.0kbitsframe=  780 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   54016kB time=00:00:31.57 bitrate=14015.0kbitsframe=  792 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   55040kB time=00:00:31.97 bitrate=14099.6kbitsframe=  804 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   56064kB time=00:00:32.36 bitrate=14191.6kbitsframe=  816 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   56832kB time=00:00:32.76 bitrate=14208.0kbitsframe=  827 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   57856kB time=00:00:33.19 bitrate=14278.1kbitsframe=  840 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   58880kB time=00:00:33.96 bitrate=14202.2kbitsframe=  852 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   59648kB time=00:00:34.36 bitrate=14217.8kbitsframe=  864 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   60672kB time=00:00:34.77 bitrate=14293.3kbitsframe=  876 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   61184kB time=00:00:35.17 bitrate=14247.8kbitsframe=  887 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   61440kB time=00:00:35.58 bitrate=14144.5kbitsframe=  900 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   62208kB time=00:00:36.37 bitrate=14010.5kbitsframe=  912 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   63232kB time=00:00:36.77 bitrate=14084.2kbitsframe=  924 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   64000kB time=00:00:37.16 bitrate=14107.9kbitsframe=  936 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   64768kB time=00:00:37.56 bitrate=14123.2kbitsframe=  947 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   65536kB time=00:00:37.99 bitrate=14130.2kbitsframe=  960 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   66304kB time=00:00:38.76 bitrate=14012.5kbitsframe=  972 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   67328kB time=00:00:39.16 bitrate=14081.7kbitsframe=  984 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   68096kB time=00:00:39.57 bitrate=14096.4kbitsframe=  996 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   68864kB time=00:00:39.95 bitrate=14118.4kbitsframe= 1007 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   69632kB time=00:00:40.38 bitrate=14125.0kbitsframe= 1020 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   70400kB time=00:00:41.17 bitrate=14007.1kbitsframe= 1032 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   71424kB time=00:00:41.55 bitrate=14079.5kbitsframe= 1044 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   72192kB time=00:00:41.96 bitrate=14093.4kbitsframe= 1056 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   72960kB time=00:00:42.36 bitrate=14107.1kbitsframe= 1067 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   73728kB time=00:00:42.79 bitrate=14113.4kbitsframe= 1080 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   74496kB time=00:00:43.56 bitrate=14009.0kbitsframe= 1092 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   75520kB time=00:00:43.96 bitrate=14070.7kbitsframe= 1104 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   76288kB time=00:00:44.37 bitrate=14083.9kbitsframe= 1116 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   77056kB time=00:00:44.75 bitrate=14103.7kbitsframe= 1127 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   77824kB time=00:00:45.18 bitrate=14109.7kbitsframe= 1140 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   78592kB time=00:00:45.97 bitrate=14004.3kbitsframe= 1152 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   79616kB time=00:00:46.35 bitrate=14069.3kbitsframe= 1164 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   80384kB time=00:00:46.76 bitrate=14081.9kbitsframe= 1176 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   81152kB time=00:00:47.16 bitrate=14094.2kbitsframe= 1187 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   81920kB time=00:00:47.59 bitrate=14100.1kbitsframe= 1200 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   82688kB time=00:00:48.36 bitrate=14006.3kbitsframe= 1212 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   83712kB time=00:00:48.76 bitrate=14061.9kbitsframe= 1224 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   84480kB time=00:00:49.17 bitrate=14073.9kbitsframe= 1236 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=   85248kB time=00:00:49.57 bitrate=14085.7kbitsframe= 1247 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   86016kB time=00:00:49.98 bitrate=14097.4kbitsframe= 1260 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   86784kB time=00:00:50.77 bitrate=14002.1kbitsframe= 1272 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   87808kB time=00:00:51.17 bitrate=14055.1kbitsframe= 1284 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   88576kB time=00:00:51.56 bitrate=14072.5kbitsframe= 1296 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   89344kB time=00:00:51.96 bitrate=14083.8kbitsframe= 1307 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   90112kB time=00:00:52.39 bitrate=14089.2kbitsframe= 1320 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   90880kB time=00:00:53.16 bitrate=14004.0kbitsframe= 1332 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   91904kB time=00:00:53.56 bitrate=14054.6kbitsframe= 1344 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   92672kB time=00:00:53.97 bitrate=14065.6kbitsframe= 1356 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   93440kB time=00:00:54.37 bitrate=14076.5kbitsframe= 1367 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   94208kB time=00:00:54.78 bitrate=14087.2kbitsframe= 1379 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   94976kB time=00:00:55.57 bitrate=14000.3kbitsframe= 1387 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   95488kB time=00:00:55.59 bitrate=14070.4kbitsframe= 1399 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   96256kB time=00:00:56.36 bitrate=13990.3kbitsframe= 1411 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   97280kB time=00:00:56.76 bitrate=14038.2kbitsframe= 1423 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   98048kB time=00:00:57.17 bitrate=14048.7kbitsframe= 1434 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   98816kB time=00:00:57.57 bitrate=14059.0kbitsframe= 1446 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=   99584kB time=00:00:57.96 bitrate=14074.4kbitsframe= 1457 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  100352kB time=00:00:58.38 bitrate=14079.4kbitsframe= 1470 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  101120kB time=00:00:59.17 bitrate=13997.9kbitsframe= 1482 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  102144kB time=00:00:59.56 bitrate=14048.5kbitsframe= 1494 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  102912kB time=00:00:59.96 bitrate=14058.4kbitsframe= 1506 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  103680kB time=00:01:00.37 bitrate=14068.2kbitsframe= 1517 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  104704kB time=00:01:00.77 bitrate=14112.4kbitsframe= 1527 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  108032kB time=00:01:01.16 bitrate=14469.6kbitsframe= 1537 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  111616kB time=00:01:01.56 bitrate=14851.2kbitsframe= 1549 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  114688kB time=00:01:02.35 bitrate=15066.8kbitsframe= 1561 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  117504kB time=00:01:02.76 bitrate=15337.0kbitsframe= 1573 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  120576kB time=00:01:03.16 bitrate=15637.0kbitsframe= 1585 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  123904kB time=00:01:03.57 bitrate=15966.2kbitsframe= 1597 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  127488kB time=00:01:03.95 bitrate=16329.4kbitsframe= 1609 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  131072kB time=00:01:04.76 bitrate=16578.3kbitsframe= 1621 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  134912kB time=00:01:05.17 bitrate=16957.8kbitsframe= 1633 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  139264kB time=00:01:05.55 bitrate=17402.3kbitsframe= 1645 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  141056kB time=00:01:05.96 bitrate=17518.0kbitsframe= 1657 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  141824kB time=00:01:06.36 bitrate=17505.8kbitsframe= 1669 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  142592kB time=00:01:07.15 bitrate=17393.7kbitsframe= 1681 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  143360kB time=00:01:07.56 bitrate=17382.5kbitsframe= 1693 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  144384kB time=00:01:07.96 bitrate=17402.2kbitsframe= 1705 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  145152kB time=00:01:08.37 bitrate=17391.1kbitsframe= 1717 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  145920kB time=00:01:08.75 bitrate=17385.4kbitsframe= 1729 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  146688kB time=00:01:09.56 bitrate=17273.3kbitsframe= 1741 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  147456kB time=00:01:09.97 bitrate=17263.1kbitsframe= 1753 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  148480kB time=00:01:10.35 bitrate=17288.2kbitsframe= 1765 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  149248kB time=00:01:10.76 bitrate=17278.0kbitsframe= 1777 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  150016kB time=00:01:11.16 bitrate=17268.0kbitsframe= 1789 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  150784kB time=00:01:11.97 bitrate=17161.0kbitsframe= 1801 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  151552kB time=00:01:12.36 bitrate=17156.8kbitsframe= 1813 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  152576kB time=00:01:12.76 bitrate=17176.5kbitsframe= 1825 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  153344kB time=00:01:13.17 bitrate=17167.4kbitsframe= 1837 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  154112kB time=00:01:13.57 bitrate=17158.3kbitsframe= 1849 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  154880kB time=00:01:14.36 bitrate=17060.8kbitsframe= 1861 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  155648kB time=00:01:14.77 bitrate=17052.5kbitsframe= 1873 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  156672kB time=00:01:15.17 bitrate=17072.1kbitsframe= 1885 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  157440kB time=00:01:15.56 bitrate=17068.6kbitsframe= 1897 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  158208kB time=00:01:15.96 bitrate=17060.3kbitsframe= 1909 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  158976kB time=00:01:16.77 bitrate=16962.2kbitsframe= 1921 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  159744kB time=00:01:17.16 bitrate=16959.3kbitsframe= 1933 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  160768kB time=00:01:17.56 bitrate=16978.8kbitsframe= 1945 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  161536kB time=00:01:17.97 bitrate=16971.2kbitsframe= 1953 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  162048kB time=00:01:18.37 bitrate=16937.0kbitsframe= 1966 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  163072kB time=00:01:18.76 bitrate=16960.9kbitsframe= 1977 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  163584kB time=00:01:19.18 bitrate=16922.5kbitsframe= 1989 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  164608kB time=00:01:19.97 bitrate=16860.4kbitsframe= 2000 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  165376kB time=00:01:20.36 bitrate=16858.1kbitsframe= 2009 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  165888kB time=00:01:20.76 bitrate=16825.4kbitsframe= 2021 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  166656kB time=00:01:21.17 bitrate=16818.9kbitsframe= 2033 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  167424kB time=00:01:21.57 bitrate=16812.5kbitsframe= 2044 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  168192kB time=00:01:21.96 bitrate=16810.4kbitsframe= 2056 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  169216kB time=00:01:22.36 bitrate=16829.6kbitsframe= 2067 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  169728kB time=00:01:22.79 bitrate=16793.5kbitsframe= 2080 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  170752kB time=00:01:23.56 bitrate=16739.5kbitsframe= 2092 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  171520kB time=00:01:23.96 bitrate=16733.7kbitsframe= 2104 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  172288kB time=00:01:24.37 bitrate=16727.8kbitsframe= 2116 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  173312kB time=00:01:24.77 bitrate=16746.8kbitsframe= 2127 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  173824kB time=00:01:25.16 bitrate=16720.5kbitsframe= 2137 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  174592kB time=00:01:25.58 bitrate=16710.7kbitsframe= 2147 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  175360kB time=00:01:25.97 bitrate=16709.2kbitsframe= 2157 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  175872kB time=00:01:26.37 bitrate=16679.4kbitsframe= 2170 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  176896kB time=00:01:27.16 bitrate=16624.6kbitsframe= 2182 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  177664kB time=00:01:27.57 bitrate=16619.5kbitsframe= 2194 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  178432kB time=00:01:27.95 bitrate=16618.5kbitsframe= 2206 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  179456kB time=00:01:28.36 bitrate=16637.2kbitsframe= 2217 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  179968kB time=00:01:28.78 bitrate=16604.5kbitsframe= 2230 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  180992kB time=00:01:29.55 bitrate=16555.7kbitsframe= 2242 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  181760kB time=00:01:29.96 bitrate=16551.1kbitsframe= 2254 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  182528kB time=00:01:30.36 bitrate=16546.5kbitsframe= 2266 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  183552kB time=00:01:30.77 bitrate=16565.0kbitsframe= 2277 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  184064kB time=00:01:31.17 bitrate=16537.3kbitsframe= 2290 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  185088kB time=00:01:31.96 bitrate=16486.6kbitsframe= 2302 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  185856kB time=00:01:32.37 bitrate=16482.4kbitsframe= 2314 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  186624kB time=00:01:32.75 bitrate=16482.0kbitsframe= 2326 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  187648kB time=00:01:33.16 bitrate=16500.3kbitsframe= 2337 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  188160kB time=00:01:33.56 bitrate=16473.7kbitsframe= 2347 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  188928kB time=00:01:33.97 bitrate=16469.5kbitsframe= 2357 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  189696kB time=00:01:34.35 bitrate=16469.2kbitsframe= 2367 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  190208kB time=00:01:34.78 bitrate=16439.3kbitsframe= 2377 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  190976kB time=00:01:35.18 bitrate=16435.4kbitsframe= 2390 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  192000kB time=00:01:35.97 bitrate=16387.6kbitsframe= 2401 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  192768kB time=00:01:36.36 bitrate=16387.6kbitsframe= 2410 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  193280kB time=00:01:36.76 bitrate=16362.3kbitsframe= 2422 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  194048kB time=00:01:37.17 bitrate=16358.8kbitsframe= 2434 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  194816kB time=00:01:37.57 bitrate=16355.3kbitsframe= 2446 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  195840kB time=00:01:37.96 bitrate=16376.9kbitsframe= 2457 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  196352kB time=00:01:38.38 bitrate=16348.5kbitsframe= 2470 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  197376kB time=00:01:39.17 bitrate=16302.9kbitsframe= 2482 fps= 22 q=-0.0 size=  198144kB time=00:01:39.56 bitrate=16303.3kbitsframe= 2494 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  198912kB time=00:01:39.96 bitrate=16300.1kbitsframe= 2506 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  199936kB time=00:01:40.37 bitrate=16317.8kbitsframe= 2517 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  200448kB time=00:01:40.80 bitrate=16290.4kbitsframe= 2530 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  201472kB time=00:01:41.56 bitrate=16249.8kbitsframe= 2542 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  202240kB time=00:01:41.97 bitrate=16246.9kbitsframe= 2554 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  203008kB time=00:01:42.37 bitrate=16244.0kbitsframe= 2566 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  204032kB time=00:01:42.76 bitrate=16265.0kbitsframe= 2577 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  204544kB time=00:01:43.18 bitrate=16238.4kbitsframe= 2590 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  205568kB time=00:01:43.97 bitrate=16195.8kbitsframe= 2602 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  206336kB time=00:01:44.36 bitrate=16196.5kbitsframe= 2614 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  207104kB time=00:01:44.76 bitrate=16193.8kbitsframe= 2626 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  208128kB time=00:01:45.17 bitrate=16211.2kbitsframe= 2636 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  208640kB time=00:01:45.57 bitrate=16188.7kbitsframe= 2645 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  209408kB time=00:01:45.96 bitrate=16189.4kbitsframe= 2657 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  210176kB time=00:01:46.36 bitrate=16186.8kbitsframe= 2667 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  210688kB time=00:01:46.79 bitrate=16161.4kbitsframe= 2677 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  211456kB time=00:01:47.20 bitrate=16159.0kbitsframe= 2689 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  212224kB time=00:01:47.96 bitrate=16102.4kbitsframe= 2701 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  213248kB time=00:01:48.37 bitrate=16119.5kbitsframe= 2713 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  214016kB time=00:01:48.77 bitrate=16117.3kbitsframe= 2725 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  214784kB time=00:01:49.16 bitrate=16118.2kbitsframe= 2737 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  215552kB time=00:01:49.56 bitrate=16116.0kbitsframe= 2749 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  216320kB time=00:01:50.35 bitrate=16057.8kbitsframe= 2760 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  217088kB time=00:01:50.76 bitrate=16055.8kbitsframe= 2770 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  217856kB time=00:01:51.16 bitrate=16053.9kbitsframe= 2780 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  218624kB time=00:01:51.57 bitrate=16051.9kbitsframe= 2790 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  219136kB time=00:01:51.95 bitrate=16034.3kbitsframe= 2801 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  219904kB time=00:01:52.36 bitrate=16032.5kbitsframe= 2813 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  220672kB time=00:01:52.76 bitrate=16030.7kbitsframe= 2825 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  221696kB time=00:01:53.17 bitrate=16047.4kbitsframe= 2837 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  222464kB time=00:01:53.55 bitrate=16048.5kbitsframe= 2849 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  223232kB time=00:01:54.36 bitrate=15989.8kbitsframe= 2861 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  224000kB time=00:01:54.77 bitrate=15988.1kbitsframe= 2873 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  224768kB time=00:01:55.15 bitrate=15989.4kbitsframe= 2885 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  225792kB time=00:01:55.56 bitrate=16005.9kbitsframe= 2897 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  226560kB time=00:01:55.96 bitrate=16004.2kbitsframe= 2909 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  227328kB time=00:01:56.75 bitrate=15949.9kbitsframe= 2921 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  228096kB time=00:01:57.16 bitrate=15948.4kbitsframe= 2933 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  228864kB time=00:01:57.56 bitrate=15947.0kbitsframe= 2943 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  229632kB time=00:01:57.97 bitrate=15945.5kbitsframe= 2954 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  230400kB time=00:01:58.35 bitrate=15946.9kbitsframe= 2965 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  231168kB time=00:01:58.76 bitrate=15945.5kbitsframe= 2976 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  231936kB time=00:01:59.16 bitrate=15944.0kbitsframe= 2987 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  232704kB time=00:01:59.57 bitrate=15942.6kbitsframe= 2997 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=  233216kB time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=15920.9kbitsframe= 3001 fps= 21 q=-0.0 Lsize=  234612kB time=00:02:00.04 bitrate=16010.5kbits/s speed=0.849x    
video:234441kB audio:104kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.028714%
[aac @ 0x7fb1a4812a00] Qavg: 63503.863
```

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan full log has been added!